# Find the probability of drawing a specific card after drawung an ace

Tags: probability

Given a deck of $52$ well mixed cards, we draw cards until we get the first ace. What of the following events has higher pribability of occuring: the next card, after the first ace was drawn, is a spade ace compared to hearts-2?

I want to see this from the persoective of conditional probability. In case of spade ace,
$$\mathbb{P}(spade\, ace|ace) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(spade\, ace \cap ace)}{\mathbb{P}(ace)}=\frac{1/3}{3/n},$$ where $n$ represents the number of not yet drawn cards. At the other hand, if the first ace was already spade, then the probability of the next card being ace spade will be 0. I do not know how to go from here. Can you privide some suggestion or a solution proposal? Thanks.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380974/probability-of-the-card-following-first-ace-being-ace-of-spades-or-two-of-clubs?rq=1). The solution doesn't use conditional probability, but that's because using it is cumbersome for the very reason you mention. One must consider, instead, the entire shuffling of the deck as a complete experiment and analyze it rather than go card-by-card (which is what you're suggesting by fixing $n$). You've already pointed out, by getting stuck, the futility of the conditional approach : it's not appropriate here.